# VirtualBox image from running VPS

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vps

I have an Ubuntu Server 10.04 VPS (Virtual Private Server) that hosts my website. I would like to clone this VPS and create a VirtualBox machine from it. How can I do this?

Comment: What VPS technology is the host using?

Comment: +1 to Matt. To amplify: "VPS" is a general term, and can apply to several different virtualization technologies. It's perfectly possible your VPS already *is* a VirtualBox image.

Comment: My VPS is using Xen HVM. An additional difficulty is that my VPS server is using Ubuntu Server amd64 edition while my develpment PC (the one I'm trying to port my VPS to) has an i386 architecture.

Comment: You hosting provider might actually offer this service to you, try asking them?